# Bash: Copy to home directory

Tags: bash, users, home-directory, copy

A bash script is used to copy a file to startup directory. It works fine when the username (ashok) is explicitly given:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/syncthing-start.desktop /home/ashok/.config/autostart
```

Since the script is meant for multiple users, I tried to modify the code, so that the username is not to be given, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/syncthing-start.desktop /home/$USER/.config/autostart
```

In the later case, the script shows the error:

```
cp: failed to access '/home/root/.config/autostart': Not a directory.
```

Does anybody know a workaround?

Comment: How should it resolve? to the user executing the script? or some other user?

Comment: @SteelDriver, The script is meant to copy a file to the desired directory (home/.config), without giving the username. Since I am new to script writing, I thought someone can point out the right way to get the username (here the error prints /home/root, instead of /home/ashok)

Comment: Instead of assuming the home directory give $USER, use the user's actual home directory with `$HOME`

Comment: @Steekdriver, it should be resolved to the user executing the script. Thanks for repeating your question.

Comment: @steeldriver, giving $SUDO_USER resolved the issue. Thanks a lot for the comment.

Comment: @Ashok think this is what you are looking for [using-systemd](https://docs.syncthing.net/users/autostart.html#using-systemd)

Comment: Running `systemctl --user enable --now syncthing.service` as the user you intend to start syncthing for should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

To have [global autostart](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/0.5/ar01s02.html) you have to copy this file to `/etc/xdg/autostart` by the below command:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/syncthing-start.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/
```

and reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP wants the user's home that executed the script he should include:

```
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ] ; then
  echo "Sorry, but you are not root. Use sudo to run"
  exit 1
fi
```

By enforcing the user to use "sudo" the $USER_SUDO should do exactly what the OP wanted to achieve.

Comment: Note that nothing guarantees the home directory of a user to be a subdirectory of /home, or to be named the same as the username. The `root` user is the most common and prominent counterexample, though not the only one.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be resolved by using $SUDO_USER, instead of $USER. The complete script then would be:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/syncthing-start.desktop /home/$SUDO_USER/.config/autostart
```

Comment: Actually I don't think this is a good way to solve the issue - aside from [the issue mentioned by gelnn jackman](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1322629/bash-copy-to-home-directory#comment2254042_1322629) `$SUDO_USER` will be resolved by the shell rather than the sudo command itself, so will rely on the *script* being executed with sudo as well